# Postgres add value to text array if colums aren't null

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have this code

```
DECLARE 
  email TEXT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'email');
  workspace_name TEXT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'hd');
  name TEXT := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'name');
  is_admin BOOLEAN := ((current_setting('request.jwt.claims'::TEXT, TRUE))::JSON ->> 'isAdmin')::BOOLEAN;
  onboarding_complete BOOLEAN;
  w_id bigint;
  connected TEXT[];
  result initial_user_data%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT workspaces.id, workspaces.onboarding_complete INTO w_id, onboarding_complete FROM workspaces WHERE domain_name = workspace_name;
  
  -- Assign values to the result record type
  result.email := email;
  result.name := name;
  result.workspace_name := workspace_name;
  result.is_admin := is_admin;
  result.onboarding_complete := onboarding_complete;
  result.workspace_id := w_id;
  
  -- Add services to the array
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services_connected wt WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id AND google IS NOT NULL) THEN
    connected := array_append(connected, 'google');
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services_connected wt WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id AND github IS NOT NULL) THEN
    connected := array_append(connected, 'github');
  END IF;
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services_connected wt WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id AND zoom IS NOT NULL) THEN
    connected := array_append(connected, 'zoom');
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services_connected wt WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id AND jira IS NOT NULL) THEN
    connected := array_append(connected, 'jira');
  END IF;
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services_connected wt WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id AND notion IS NOT NULL) THEN
    connected := array_append(connected, 'notion');
  END IF;
  
  -- Assign the array of services to the result variable
  result.services_connected := connected;
  
  RETURN result;
END;
```

Here, I am making repeated calls to same table

```
 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM services_connected wt WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id AND google IS NOT NULL) THEN
    connected := array_append(connected, 'google');
  END IF;
```

How can I compress it into single query?

Answer (score 2):

I think a possible solution is something like:

```
SELECT ARRAY_REMOVE(ARRAY[
  CASE WHEN google IS NOT NULL THEN 'google' END,
  CASE WHEN github IS NOT NULL THEN 'github' END,
  CASE WHEN zoom IS NOT NULL THEN 'zoom' END,
  CASE WHEN jira IS NOT NULL THEN 'jira' END,
  CASE WHEN notion IS NOT NULL THEN 'notion' END], null)
  INTO connected
FROM services_connected wt
WHERE wt.workspace_id = w_id
```

The idea is to have the single query generate the array instead of concatenating each result. Since this includes nulls for the columns that are null, it uses `Array_REMOVE(..., null)` after to clear it up so it only includes the set strings. You can see the basic idea [working in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HYo1Kf9j).

I think the above might work for you, however, if possible, I would consider renormalizing your table. It would make a lot more sense to me if your table was less like...

| workspace_id | google | github |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |

... and more like ...

| workspace_id | service | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Google | 1 |
| 1 | Github | 1 |
| 2 | Google | 1 |
| 2 | Github | 1 |

This would let you select the list of service strings for each `workplace_id` easily without needing the string names in your query, and it would let you add additional services without changing the table structure.